# Can anyone verify my proof that there is no non-constant polynomial with real coefficients which outputs a prime number for every natural number?

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, prime-numbers, real-numbers

My problem is contained in the title. I have a proof, but I'm here to do two things: 1, check that my proof is $correct$, and 2, ask if anyone has a simpler proof. (I think my proof is quite pretty but I feel like there must be nicer proofs out there.) (the wordiness of my proof could definitely be simplified, but I felt it was necessary to make my thoughts as clear as possible since that's part of the point of this post.)

First, it is clear that our polynomial cannot evaluate to the same prime infinitely many times, as otherwise for such a polynomial $f(x), g(x) = f(x)-p$ (where $p$ is said prime) has infinitely many roots, which we can show to be the zero polynomial without appealing to the FTA, so $f(x)$ would be constant.

Next, we prove the case with integer coefficients. For some prime $p$, we have $f(1)=p$ and $1\equiv1+kp\pmod p, k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and since modular arithmetic is compatible with polynomial evaluation when said polynomial has integer coefficients, we have $f(1) \equiv f(1+kp)\pmod{p} \to 0 \equiv f(1+kp)\pmod{p}$, so for every $k$, we have a value of the function which is congruent to a prime, meaning it either evaluates to a multiple of the prime or the prime infinitely many times, both of which do not work.

Now, we move on to rational coefficients. Let our polynomial be $f(x)$, which can be written as $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{p_k}{q_k}x^k$. Pick $x$ to be $t(q_1\cdot q_2 \dots q_{n-1} \cdot q_n), t \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Clearly $\frac{p_0}{q_0}$ is an integer, so we have a polynomial in $t$ with integer coefficients that evaluates to a prime for every positive natural number, which is impossible.

Then, we consider real coefficients. Since $f(a)$ evaluates to an integer for every positive natural number $a$, we know the finite differences between different values of $f(a)$ are integers, so taking them at $0$, we have $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^k[f](0)$, meaning $f(x)$ must have rational coefficients.*

QED.

Note: I am looking for $verification$ first and foremost. A different proof is just icing on the cake. (if you can't verify but have a different solution please still post it it would be greatly appreciated)

Thank you in advance!

*If this doesn't work (although I think it should - please let me know if I'm wrong), we can also use the Vandermonde Matrix to show that any polynomial which evaluates to integers for all positive naturals must have rational coefficients. However, the proof that the Vandermonde Matrix is invertible isn't very nice/elementary. I would appreciate a simple way to prove either that the matrix is invertible or a simple way to show that a polynomial which evaluates to integers for positive integers must have rational coefficients.

Comment: Usually, integer coefficients are assumed , but the proof can be extended to the case of rational coefficients. If irrational coefficients occur, I guess that it can be shown that the polynomial cannot be an integer for every natural number although I have never thought about that.

Comment: @Peter I think we can say something more general, like: if $F$ is field with characteristic zero, $F'$ is it's subfield, $p$ is polynomial over $F$ with degree $n$  and for $n+1$ different $x_i \in F'$ we have $p(x_i) \in F'$, then $p$ has coefficients from $F'$.